# How can I manually trigger the rendering of the default google sign in button

Tags: angularjs, google-oauth

Here is a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/12jpL138/) of my problem.

I'm using the default google sign in button by following the tutorial found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).  I've included all of the resources required in an Angular application.  The button is included in a view that contains login options.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

### When it works

When loading that partial view with the initial load of the site, it all works wonderfully.

### When it doesn't

When the partial view that contains the button is loaded after the initial page load (like when someone navigates to the registration page after initial load), the button is not rendered.  Obviously something is being auto-wired up when the button is present that I need to manually trigger when the button is only available later, but I don't see any documentation on that anywhere when using the default button.  Is there a function on the gapi that I need to call to wire up the button?

### As a side note

I can't figure out why I'm having so much trouble with google oauth.  I feel like I'm missing a basic concept that's making it impossible to figure out anything on my own, so if there is a resource you would suggest I read to really get it (especially when it comes to integrating into an angular app), I'd be very grateful for the pointer.

Comment: hey sonicblis, I didn't quite get it. Can you post some code or a code pen? thx

Comment: totally fair:  http://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/12jpL138/.  If you take the button out of the template and put it in the main page, it renders fine.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/12jpL138/3/

The key is to use `gapi.signin2.render` to create the button, which incidentally also allows you to function within the scope of an angular controller which is wonderful.

By making the button a placeholder like so:

```
<div id="googleButtonPlaceholder"></div>
```

I can then use the render function of the `gapi` to reference it and wire it all up, which calls all of the auto auth things the library does automatically to log the user in and whatnot.  This greatly simplifies things for my angular app.

```
$window.gapi.signin2.render('googleButtonPlaceholder', {
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    'width': 200,
    'height': 50,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'dark',
    'onsuccess': $scope.federateWithGoogle
});
```